# Algorithm to colorize C-like /* comment blocks */

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing, semantics

I have a simple text editor. I'd like to add a C-like `/* comment blocks */` colorizer to it.
I mean multi-line comments of course.

Its data structure looks as follows:

```
struct TextEdit
{
    struct Line
    {
        char* str;
        int len;
    };

    Line* index;
    int lines;

    void Modified( int line_from, int line_to );

    bool IsInBlockComment( int line, int column );
};
```

`Modified()` is called every time the text is modified so the editor has a chance to re-scan the contents of the modified range of lines.

- How would you implement the `IsInBlockComment()` method which can determine if a given position in text is inside a block comment?
- What extra data should be added and maintained by `Modified()` to be able to do it efficiently?

Important detail:

`/*` and `*/` tokens should not be in effect if they occur after a `//` comment or inside `""` and `''` literal strings.

I'm not asking for working source code or detailed specs, I ask for a brief concept only.

Comment: It is not really a trivial task. You'll have to implement a parser that takes care of single-line comments and strings.

Comment: It already parses single line comments and '' "" literals, the big thing is with /* */, in that way I would NOT need to reparse entire document every time it has tiny change as indicated by Modified method.

Comment: The `struct` doesn't look like it's C but C++.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: linked list of /* open and */ close positions in text, doesn't help much hard to maintain as line numbers of non-modified lines changes very often. I tried also extra flag per line indicating that this line entirely is inside block comment - was bit better. But my question is about your ideas not mine :)

Comment: @Anonymous you always should present your own research effort on a question, even if it is unsuccessful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all notice that C supports multiline strings, so you already had this problem, just not addressed it.

Your parser engine has a *state*. You have to know whether you're inside a literal string or a C like comment, etc.

Store this state for the starting position of each line. This way the parser can pick up where it left off.
If the new state of the the next line differs from the old one, you have to continue parsing, otherwise you can stop.

By controlling the frequency of such state snapshots (e.g.: storing it only for every 10th line) you can control the trade-off between speed and memory footprint.

Comment: Good one, is this possible to detect somehow after re-parsing modified block when to stop parsing? I don't really want to re-parse till end of file. Is this enough to check if previous parsing state was same as current parser?

Comment: Yes. I've already told this in the answer.

Comment: It is brillant answer! Saved me a lot of time trying other things and gives optimal performance, it is easy to maintain and has realy low extra storage needs.